# vim syntax highlighting ubuntu touch

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, vim, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to get syntax highlighting working while using vim.

```
:version
```

gives me: "Small version without GUI".

I installed both "vim-gui-common" and "vim-runtime", but everytime I issue the command

```
:syntax on
```

I get `e319: sorry, the command is not available in this version`

```
dpkg -l | grep vim
```

gives me

```
ii  vim-common                                           2:7.4.488-3ubuntu2                                         armhf        Vi IMproved - Common files

ii  vim-gui-common                                       2:7.4.488-3ubuntu2                                         all          Vi IMproved - Common GUI files

ii  vim-runtime                                          2:7.4.488-3ubuntu2                                         all          Vi IMproved - Runtime files

ii  vim-tiny                                             2:7.4.488-3ubuntu2                                         armhf        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - compact version
```

I'm running in a chroot (ubuntu 15.04 touch armhf) in ubuntu-touch (aquaris m10)

**Solved** as muru suggested I installed "vim" (instead of "vim-tiny") and now the syntax highlighting works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the actual binary is from `vim-tiny`, that's what you'll get. The feature has to be compiled into the executable of Vim. Install one of `vim-nox`, `vim-gnome`, `vim-gtk`, etc., instead.